# Multiple states and urls for the same template

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm building a web application and I have a screen that consists in five sections, each section represents a level, the areas are the higher level of my tree, when I click in any card of the area, the system should return the skills of that area and so on.
[image: wireframe]

I need to change the url and state according what the user is accessing, for example, if the user access some skill, the url must be

```
example.com/#/curriculum/skill/<skillId>
```

and if I access this link it should automatically load the capabilities from this skill and his parent which is area in this case.

I have one controller for area, skill, capability, knowledge and criteria, in each controller I have a action to load the next level of the tree, which looks like that

```
$scope.loadSkills = function (id) {
   Area.loadSkills(...)
   $state.go('curriculo.skill', {id: this.current.id}, {nofity: false, reload: false});
}
```

And these are my states

```
$stateProvider
      .state('curriculum', {
        url: '/curriculum',
        templateUrl: '/templates/curriculo.html',
      })
      .state('curriculum.are', {
        url: '/area/:id',
        template: '',
      })
      .state('curriculum.skill', {
        url: '/skill/:id',
        template: '',
      })
      .state('curriculum.capability', {
        url: '/capability/:id',
      })
      .state('curriculum.knowledge', {
        url: '/knowledge/:id',
      })
      .state('curriculum.criteria', {
        url: '/criteria/:id',
      });
```

I'm new in Angular and I not sure about what to do, should I created multiple nested views in this case, and if so, how do I load stuff that I need according the url?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest to use the capability of multiple named views offered by the `ui-router`. You can read more about it [here](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-Views). Basically the documentation says the following:

> You can name your views so that you can have more than one ui-view per
>   template.

If you check the example in the documentation, you'll notive that there are similarities between your scenario and the example, because you want to dynamically populate a different `views` (here named views).

**Example**

I tried to recreate your scenario in this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LordTribual/p7s78mzh/).

First I created an `abstract` state which provides the different `views` like areas, skills etc. This is the template for the abstract state:

```
<div class="curriculum" ui-view="areas"></div>
<div class="curriculum" ui-view="skills"></div>
```

Next I created a nested state `curriculo.main`, which declares the different views (areas, skills etc.) you need. Each view has its own `template` and `controller`. Notice that the nested state has a `resolve` which initially loads the areas from a service called `curriculo`. If you use resolves remember that the resolve keyword **MUST** be relative to the state not the views (when using multiple views).

Basically the service is responsible for the business logic, means getting the areas, skills etc. In the JSFiddle I have hard-coded the HTTP results. Replace that with HTTP calls and make use of promises. Since each named view has its own controller we need a mechanism to notify about changes, for example to notify the `SkillsController` that skills have been loaded. Thus, I created a simple event system (subcribe-notify):

```
.factory('notifier', function($rootScope) {
    return {
        subscribe: function(scope, callback, eventName) {
            var handler = $rootScope.$on(eventName, callback);
            scope.$on('$destroy', handler);
        },
        notify: function(eventName, data) {
            $rootScope.$emit(eventName, data);
        }
    };
});
```

The `SkillsController` can then subscribe to a specific event like so:

```
notifier.subscribe($scope, function(event, data) {
    $scope.skills = data;
}, 'onSkillsLoaded');
```

The `curriculo` service calls (at the end of the `getSkills()`) `notify`and provides an event. In this case the same event as you subscribed to in the `SkillsController`.

```
notifier.notify('onSkillsLoaded', result);
```

All in all, that's the magic behind my little example. It's worth mentioning that you need to apply best practices to the code, since this is just to recreate your scenario. For best practices I suggest the [Angular Style Guide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide) by John Papa.

**Update 1**

I updated my example to show you deep linking. I simulate the deep link via

```
$state.go('.', {area: 2, skill: 5});
```

This way I can activate a certain state. Now each view has its `activate` function. Inside this function I do all the work that is neseccary for the initialization, e.g. selecting an area if the query param is set. As you know, you can access the params with the `$state` service. I had to use a `$timeout` to delay the init of the areas controller because the subscribe wasn't made yet. Please try to find a better solution to this problem. Maybe you can use promises or register each controller in a service which resolves if all controller have been initialized.

If anything has been selected I also use the `go` with an additional option to set the `notify` to `false`.

```
$state.go('.', {area: area.id, skill: skillId ? skillId : undefined}, {notify: false});
```

If `notify` is set to `false` it will prevent the controllers from being reinitialized. Thus you can only update the URL and no state change will happen.

Comment: Is there a way to change the URL according what the user is accessing?Because there is a moment that I have have to send a notification to the user and build all the structure according the given URL.
And thanks for the fast reply :)

Comment: Updated my answer. Is this what you want? But now try to implement it yourself :) come back if you have any problems. If this answer was ok, I would appreciate the acceptance.